# Pandas groupby std is much slower when using ddof=1 Why?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have discovered something unusual in pandas re the ddof (degrees of freedom) parameter for standard deviation calculations (std).

For regular std, the speed is the same whether I leave its default to 1, or specify 0. When I do it as part of a `group by`, it is around 10 times slower (the test DataFrame I set up has a similar structure to the one I am working on). The slowdown is worse for more columns/rows/unique groups.

Any idea what is going on here? Does pandas need a little bug fix? Is there a way to replicate the `ddof=1` behaviour at a faster speed (I'm running these std calculations a lot)?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100000,10))

%timeit test.std()
100 loops, best of 3: 18.2 ms per loop
%timeit test.std(ddof=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.3 ms per loop

test['group'] = (test[0]*20+1).astype(int)
test['date'] = [datetime.date(2018, 3, g) for g in test['group']]
test = test.set_index(['date','group'])

%timeit test.groupby(level='date').std()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.78 ms per loop
%timeit test.groupby(level='date').std(ddof=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 68.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, but it is a known issue.

Below is some `pandas` source code from `groupby.py`.

- `ddof == 1`: (default value) a Cythonised algorithm is applied.
- `ddof != 1`: a Python-level loop is applied.

Therefore, you won't be able to use this method to optimize from within `pandas`.

```
@Substitution(name='groupby')
@Appender(_doc_template)
def var(self, ddof=1, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Compute variance of groups, excluding missing values

    For multiple groupings, the result index will be a MultiIndex

    Parameters
    ----------
    ddof : integer, default 1
        degrees of freedom
    """
    nv.validate_groupby_func('var', args, kwargs)
    if ddof == 1:
        return self._cython_agg_general('var')
    else:
        self._set_group_selection()
        f = lambda x: x.var(ddof=ddof)
        return self._python_agg_general(f)
```

Comment: Is this reported? `ddof == 0` should be cythonized too